# Java: replace character inside a matching regex

Tags: java, regex, replace, pattern-matching

I have a string. Let's say: 
`String s = "This is my P.C.. My P.C. is the best.O.M.G!! Check this...";`

I want to replace all the `P.C.` to `PC` words and `O.M.G` to `OMG`. In general, I want to replace all the dots that are between single letters OR single letter and a space or dot. I think the matching regex for that is:

```
[^A-Za-z][A-Za-z]\\.[A-Za-z\\s\\.][^A-Za-z]
```

How can I replace only the dot from that and not everything that matches?

**EDIT:**

Expected output:

```
"This is my PC. My PC is the best.OMG!! Check this..."
```

**EDIT2:**

The basic task is to remove dots from abbreviations and acronyms that could be written with or without dots. So a good regex is also valuable

Comment: What's your expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may consider using **Positive Lookahead** to assert what follows is either a letter, dot `.` or space.

```
String s = "This is my P.C.. My P.C. is the best.O.M.G!! Check this...";
String r = s.replaceAll("([A-Z])\\.(?=[ A-Z.])", "$1");
System.out.println(r); //=> "This is my PC. My PC is the best.OMG!! Check this..."
```

Comment: I think the dot after the 'Z' needs 2 backslashes. What does $1 means?

Comment: `$1` backreferences the match result from group index 1.

Answer (score 0):

Use "lookarounds" for this. 
The `Pattern` below replaces dots **only** if preceded **and** followed by a **capital** letter.

A second iteration is recommended if you are picky and want to sanitize the `..` into `.` without affecting the suspension `...`.

```
String s = "This is my P.C.. My P.C. is the best.O.M.G!! Check this...";
//                               | preceded by capital letter
//                               |         | escaped dot
//                               |         |  | followed by capital letter
//                               |         |  |           | replace with empty String
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("(?<=[A-Z])\\.(?=[A-Z])", "")
    // second replacement: ".." folllowed by whitespace is "sanitized" with only 1 dot
    .replaceAll("\\.{2}(?=\\s)", "."));
```

**Output**

```
This is my PC. My PC. is the best.OMG!! Check this...
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the below regex which uses positive lookbehind to remove all the dots which are present just after to the Uppercase letters,

```
System.out.println("This is my P.C.. My P.C. is the best.O.M.G!! Check this...".replaceAll("(?<=[A-Z])\\.", ""));
```

**Output:**

```
This is my PC. My PC is the best.OMG!! Check this...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(?<=[A-Z])(\.)(?=[A-Z]|\.|\s)
```

You can try this.

See Demo.

http://regex101.com/r/lK9iD2/2